# Apache php fopen() does nothing

Tags: php, apache

I granted everyone everything and I cannot get fopen() to work.
My code:

```
fopen("hovno.txt", "w");
```

It does not work. It does not show any errors in log file.

```
4 drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jun 30 23:04 /var/www/
```

UPDATE: I want to create the file

Comment: what is `getcwd()` saying for you? If it's **NOT** `/var/www`, then you'rr trying to open the file somewhere else, and you HAVEN'T set the permissions right, or are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Just *create* the file? Then you can use [`touch()`](http://php.net/touch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you are using "w" as your permission mode. According to [the php man](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), you'll need to use w+ or r/r+ to read the file.

`w` only allows you to write

You're creating a new file why don't you use [file_put_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Why? I don't want to read the file. I just need to create it.

Comment: It seemed like you wanted to read the file using fopen(). Try file_put_contents http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php. edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `w+` instead of using `w`.

Comment: Why? From the docs: `w - ... If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.`